imaginary error fetching remote http image: Get "https://$path.jpg.webp": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
I'm trying to have imaginary as imageproxy and try to modify the images hosted in a Drupal with DDEV.
When I make a call to a image throught Imageproxy (http://localhost:8088/crop?width=500&height=400&url=https://imageproxy.ddev.site/sites/default/files/styles/wide/public/2024-11/8vwp5n_0.jpg.webp ) I get this error:

'error fetching remote http image: Get
"https://imageproxy.ddev.site/sites/default/files/styles/wide/public/2024-11/8vwp5n_0.jpg.webp":
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused'

Also I have check the browser response header:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: application/json Server:
imaginary 1.2.4 (bimg 1.1.4) X-Ratelimit-Limit: 101
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 100 X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1 Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024
16:20:49 GMT Content-Length: 215

If I use the imageproxy with another image: http://localhost:8088/crop?width=500&height=200&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2non/imaginary/master/testdata/smart-crop.jpg
And it works, and the browser response header:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 12904 Content-Type: image/jpeg Server:
imaginary 1.2.4 (bimg 1.1.4) X-Ratelimit-Limit: 101
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 100 X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1 Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024
16:21:59 GMT

Imaginary is been runing the docker-compose from the repository, I don't change nothing:
version: "3"

services:
  imaginary:
    image: h2non/imaginary
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      - PORT=8088
    command: -concurrency 50 -enable-url-source

Also, DDEV it's running with the standar configuration, I don't see any option to modify maybe to let imaginary to make a request to the server.

Docker containers are unable to communicate with each other if you don't network them to communicate. By default ddev creates its own Docker network ddev_default, which its containers use to communicate with each other.
Below I'll outline how you can fix this using your current docker-compose setup, but this really should be added as an additional ddev service so that it's added to your version control as part of your ddev setup.
To get your external docker-compose project to communicate with ddev you need to

Add your imaginary docker container to ddev's external network
Route requests to your ddev domain through the ddev-router container
Update the root cert store on the imaginary container to trust the SSL connection made to your ddev container

I've modified your imaginary's docker-composer file below based on what would be expected in a standard ddev setup on Linux:
# docker-compose.yaml (for imaginary)
services:
  imaginary:
    image: h2non/imaginary
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      - PORT=8088
    command: -concurrency 50 -enable-url-source
    # Route your ddev domain imageproxy.ddev.site through the ddev router container
    external_links:
      - ddev-router:imageproxy.ddev.site
    # Add this container to the default ddev network so containers can communicate
    networks:
      - ddev_default
    # Mount host's cert store in container to avoid untrusted local dev SSL cert errors.
    # This assumes a standard linux host using mkcert as per ddev install docs.
    volumes:
      - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro

# Let docker know that the ddev_default network is defined externally (by ddev)
networks:
    ddev_default:
        external: true

